# How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object which is in an another object

Tags: javascript, object, keyvaluepair

I'm asking your help for the following code:

```
function vimeoImport() {

let videosToBeImported = [{
    uri: "/videos/442638455",
    name: "FOMME_1387_VD1",
    modifed_time: "2020-07-29T09:24:48+00:00"
},{
    uri: "/videos/442056086",
    name: "FOMME_1387_VD2",
    modifed_time: "2020-07-29T09:25:27+00:00"
},{
    uri: "/videos/442638455",
    name: "FOMME_2387_VD1",
    modifed_time: "2020-07-29T09:24:48+00:00"
}];

let frtVideoUrlValues = {};

for (var index in videosToBeImported) {
    var videos = videosToBeImported[index];
    let videoName = videos.name;

    let splitName = videoName.split('_');
    let targetedVariationGroup = splitName[0].concat('_', splitName[1]);
    let positionvideo = splitName[2];

    let variationGroupParams = {};
    variationGroupParams[positionvideo] = videos.uri;
    if (targetedVariationGroup in frtVideoUrlValues) {
        frtVideoUrlValues[targetedVariationGroup] += variationGroupParams;
    } else {
        frtVideoUrlValues[targetedVariationGroup] = variationGroupParams;
    }
}
```

}

I tried to add a key/value pair (the key is a variable) in the targetedVariationGroup object which is in the frtVideoUrlValues object. When I try, I see the new key/value pair in the targetedVariationGroup but the merge is not functional and the 2 objects are not accessible:

[image]

And I try to obtain an object like this:

[image]

Comment: You care concating the objects as/like strings.

Comment: can u give an example how your output should look? It would help to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As, you didn't provide any output format, I am guessing the output should look like as follows(If this is not what you've wanted, pls provide proper output format):

```
{
  FOMME_1387: [
    { VD1: '/videos/442638455' },
    { VD2: '/videos/442056086' }
  ],
  FOMME_2387: [
    { VD1: '/videos/442638455' }
  ]
}
```

Now, to achieve this you should write code as follow:

```
function vimeoImport() {
    let videosToBeImported = [
        {
            uri: "/videos/442638455",
            name: "FOMME_1387_VD1",
            modifed_time: "2020-07-29T09:24:48+00:00"
        },
        {
            uri: "/videos/442056086",
            name: "FOMME_1387_VD2",
            modifed_time: "2020-07-29T09:25:27+00:00"
        },
        {
            uri: "/videos/442638455",
            name: "FOMME_2387_VD1",
            modifed_time: "2020-07-29T09:24:48+00:00"
        }
    ];


    let frtVideoUrlValues = {};

    for (var index in videosToBeImported) {
        var videos = videosToBeImported[index];
        let videoName = videos.name;

        let splitName = videoName.split('_');
        let targetedVariationGroup = splitName[0].concat('_', splitName[1]);
        let positionvideo = splitName[2];

        let variationGroupParams = {};
        variationGroupParams[positionvideo] = videos.uri;
        
        // here are the changes I've made
        if(frtVideoUrlValues[targetedVariationGroup] === undefined) {
            frtVideoUrlValues[targetedVariationGroup] = [];
        }

        frtVideoUrlValues[targetedVariationGroup].push(variationGroupParams);
    }

    console.log(frtVideoUrlValues);
}

vimeoImport();
```

The problem with your code is, you're using **+** to add object with another object, but **+** is only used to concat string in javascript. Instead of what you're doing, you should push objects into array. To add new elements in an array, you've to use *push()* method.

Also, notice, if key **targetedVariationGroup** in **frtVideoUrlValues** is **undefined**, I've assigned an **empty array** to **targetedVariationGroup** as follows:

```
frtVideoUrlValues[targetedVariationGroup] = [];
```

and then, pushed **variationGroupParams** object in the array as follows:

```
frtVideoUrlValues[targetedVariationGroup].push(variationGroupParams);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot reyad it helped me a lot and my problem is solved thank you :) I edited the question to display what I was expecting for, sorry I did not put this before. I hope it will help some people who will have the same problem. Have a good day!